# How the Heck do I turn off Comment Notifications?

Tags: comments

I want disable comment notifications going to the admin everytime a new comment is posted...

But I can't find this setting in the maze that EE is.

How can I turn this off? Where is this setting?

Answer (score 3):

You can adjust comment notifications in the particular Channel's preferences.

*Administration > Channels > Edit Preferences* (choose the appropriate Channel)

Then scroll down to "Notification Preferences"

[image]

[EE Docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/channels/channel_edit_preferences.html#notification-preferences)

Comment: those notification settings are all turned off but im still getting notifications. The notification im getting is from design->email notifications

Comment: That's just where the templates are managed. I'm pretty sure the notification settings are all in the Channel's preferences. Make sure *Notify the author of an entry whenever a comment is submitted?* is set to "No" as well. And double check that you are editing the right Channel's preferences.

Comment: YEah that setting is set to no, i've checked all channels and all notify settings in all channels are set to no, yet i still get them

Comment: Sounds like the setting never took in the database. Are you using EE 2.7.3? I just did a test and I think this actually might be a bug where once set to "y", `comment_notify_authors` and `comment_notify` can not be set back to "n" in the `exp_channels` table.